# Understanding GLIE conditions for epsilon greedy approach

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits, epsilon-greedy-policy

I was going through [this](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/%7Eshivaram/teaching/cs747-a2020/index.html) course on reinforcement learning (the course has two lecture videos and corresponding slides) and I had a doubt. On slide 18 of [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iAQC4mW0itfrfxPPg_0by64Lx1tk-LI4/view) pdf, it states following condition for an algorithm to have regret sublinear in T (T being number of pulls of multi arm bandit).

> **C2 - Greedy in the Limit:** Let exploit(T) denote the number of pulls that are that are greedy w.r.t the empirical mean up to horizon $T$. For sub-linear regret, we need
> $$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}[exploit(T)]}{T}=1 $$

Here, $exploit(T)$ denote the total number of "exploit" rounds performed in the first $T$ pulls. Given that expectation is defined as "the weighted sum of the outcome values, where the weights correspond to the probabilities of realizing that value",

(**Q1**) how exactly mathematically we define $\mathbb{E}[exploit(T)]$?

In second video (at 24:44), instructor has said that $\mathbb{E}[exploit(T)]$ is the number of exploit steps.

(**Q2**) Then how it equals "weighted sum of outcome values"?

(note that instructor assumes that the pulling of arm may give reward which correspond to outcome value of 1 and may not give reward which correspond to ourcome value of 0)

Also in slide 27, for GLIE-ifying $\epsilon_T$-first strategy, he selects $\epsilon_T=\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}$. Then, the instructor counts $\sqrt{T}$ exploratory pulls and $T-\sqrt{T}$ exploitory pulls. Then to show that this satisfies condition C2, instructor states $$\mathbb{E}[exploit(T)]\geq \frac{T-\sqrt{T}}{T}$$.

Here, $\frac{T-\sqrt{T}}{T}$ is a fraction of exploitory pulls.

(**Q3**) So, by above equation does the instructor mean, number of exploitory pulls is greater than equal to fraction of number of exploitory pulls?

(**Q4**) How can we put 2nd equation in first equation and still prove limit in first equation still holds, that is, how following is the case:

$$\lim_{T=\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{T-\sqrt{T}}{T}}{T}=1$$

I guess I am missing some basic concept of expectation here.